# Jquery drag n drop files without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

i made a script for drag and drop a file and upload when submit that script works thanks to Ajax, but i want it without using ajax and so without `e.preventDefault();`
just like a normal post form... how i should edit it?

```
    form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let formData = new FormData(this);
        
        for (let i = 0; i < filesLoader.length; i++) {
            formData.append(filesLoader[i][0], filesLoader[i][1])
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: form.attr('method'),
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: formData,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success")
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error")
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: So, you would like to  make a POST request when the form is submitted and as it is now the files that are dragged'n'dropped are not part of the form. To make them part of the request you now add files to the formdata object and use AJAX for posting. But you would like to avoid the AJAX and just post the form as if it was without JavaScript (and still adding the files)?

Answer (score 1):

found the solution, on Drop function i change input field too with `fileField.prop("files", e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);`
thanks to this works for both normal submit or by ajax

```
        dndFileArea.on('drop', function (e) {

            let file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
            fileField.prop("files", e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
            filesLoader.push([fileField.attr("name"), file[0]]);
```